# Randomize url alias where every time a user logs in the url is different

Tags: uri

I would like to generate a random url for a certain page every time when a user logs in to see this page. The idea is that copying the url to somebody else does not work. How would I do that?

Comment: How about restricting access by only allowing certain users to access the page instead of randomizing the url... Randomizing pages url is not good for SEO.

Comment: That's exactly what we have done :-)